# Is the game client region locked?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I am going to be buying Guild Wars 2 soon, and I was wondering if the game client is region locked in a similar manner to how it is in World of Warcraft?

For example; if I was to purchase the game in Europe, would I only be able to create characters on European servers or would I be able to create characters on both European servers and on servers based in other regions as well?

If not, is it still possible to purchase a copy of the game in Europe, and play on American servers, or do I need an American game client to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can play on whatever server and region you choose. Once you're there, you can create five characters on that server. That's it.

You can't have multiple characters on multiple servers. You *can* transfer from a server to a different server in a different region at any time — for a cost. That's what the game tells you when you join a server for the first time, anyway.

I'm in Italy and have played the free weekend on a US server. I never felt lag getting in my way, but then again I kind of suck at MMORPGs...

Comment: @Shinrai I missed the part where this is about WoW?

Comment: Freudian slip after rescanning the question again (where it's mentioned), sorry, I did mean the game in question.  (I thought GW1 was boring and I don't like PvP so I haven't touched GW2.)  It's still ridiculous if you can't roll alts on other servers - I can understand limiting the total number of characters though.

Comment: Guild Wars 2 limits characters to a single home server due to the World vs World. When guesting is brought back you'll be able to join your buddies server temporarily and play with them.

Comment: @DavidYell - Oh, okay, that makes sense.  Again, since I hate PvP that sort of thing never even occurred to me.